# How to provide custom colors to "mat-fab, mat-fab-mini, mat-button" | Angular material

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I`m facing difficulties in using my custom color for the mat-fab buttons of Angular Material.
The official doc that I am refering is [this](https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview) 

In the [official docs](https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview), we have only 3 color options:

- Primary
- Accent
- Warn

[image]

I figured out just by leaving color property empty we could make the mat-button/fab color as
"white". 
Code - `<button mat-mini-fab color="" aria-label="Icon Button background"> </button>` 
Its looks like :
[image]

While coding as well, I could see only above 3 mentioned colors :
[image]

I tired to change the css that mat-button / fab are using but nothing is working out for me.

It would be helpful if someone from the community could support me on this.

Comment: You could overwrite an existing theme like primary globally. Would that be suitable for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding `white` color you could leave the 'color' property as empty.
As I shared the code above `<button mat-mini-fab color="" aria-label="Icon Button background"> </button>`

**For the custom color:**
I`ve my **CSS** file as follows: 
[image]

**HTML file :**
Using Attribute directive for showing different colors.
[image]
**Output:**
[image]

**In the nutshell,** rather then providing `color` property in the CSS file you have to provide `background color` property.

Hope, this will be helpful for you.
Thank you.